# What is recessional nonlocality?

Tags: terminology, definition, non-locality

In laymen’s terms, what is [recessional nonlocality](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=recessional+nonlocality)? I understand recessional means to recede or retract away, and (correct me if I’m wrong) I understand locality has something to do with quantum mechanics regarding the probability of position. I do not understand the meaning of the two words conjoined.

Comment: Where did you find this term used?

Comment: @probably_someone not classified research information

Comment: Because this was something I never encountered myself I googled "recessional nonlocality". I've only found this question and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512892/what-is-recessional-nonlocality
In the comments you mention that this pair of words together was produced by some bot. Why would you think that this should make any sense???

Comment: If it really were nonlocal why doesn't depend the covariance between A and B not on C, since nonlocality means depending on all points of the considered system simultaneously ?